Automatically open folders in Forklift instead of Finder
I use Forklift (version 3.5.8) instead of Finder. When I type open . or similar to open a folder, I would like it to automatically display the folder in Forklift, not Finder.  But note that the question is not specific to the open command: I would also like applications that call on the system to open files to always have the files opened by Forklift.
Things I've tried
In the documentation in the Default File Viewer section, it explains how to set Forklift as the default file viewer.  It seems to work for some things like "show in finder", but not for other things such as open ..  Neither does it work in my Alfred workflows.
In the question How to open current folder in ForkLift from command line?, there is a discussion about creating an alternative shortcut for Forklift. But I would like Forklift to be the default behavior. I am specifically asking for a solution where system behavior is tweaked to make this happen by default.
Ideas
In the past I've seen applications that allow you to change the default app to open certain types of files.  I wonder if there is something like that for folders.
Maybe I need to upgrade to Forklift 4, but first I would want to know that this problem would actually be fixed, as I risk breaking things in the process. I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.4 right now.

One could argue that defining a shell alias actually does tweak system behavior :-)

It would change the behavior within a user shell, but then an app like Alfred wouldn't get fixed by the tweak.  I mean in theory one could write their own "open" command which somehow calls the "reveal in finder" behavior for folders and falls back to the builtin "open" for everything else.  Or maybe I could inspect the existing "open" command to see if it could be modified.

If the question is not specifically about open, it might be worth mentioning this.
